# ADT eclipse не видит исходников андроида

Tags: eclipse, android, java

работал с эклипсом несколько месяцев. пару дней назад скачал андроид 4,3 с помощью андроид SDK. указав исходники папкой C:\androidSDK\sdk\sources\android-18 продолжил работу. прошло несколько дней и эклипс снова отказался видеть их. я снова указал ему эту папку. отказ. указал .jar файл который в этой папке. отказ. ну не видит этот глючный эклипс исходников андроида и всё тут. [даже по этой ссылке скачивал. непомогло.](http://manski.net/2011/11/android-source-code-in-eclipse/#before-android-4.0)

помогите . что может быть ? эклипс этот глючный на ладан дышит

Comment: Как выход- заново скачать чистую сборку эклепса и заново указать путь к SDK. Я лично так всегда делаю, когда в нем начинает что-то глючить :-) Пару раз уже дополнение кода отваливалось, и ADT раза три. Гугление не спасло, а переустановить- на полчаса делов.

Comment: переустановил. результата нет =\

Comment: может пора перейти на Android Studio?

Comment: в двух словах о нём пожалуйста опишите... 
с удовольствием перейду с этого недобитого эклипса.

Comment: а чем студия лучше идеи? (база то одна)

просто стоит идея а студия чего то поругалась и не запустилась (плюнул и не стал париться), от того и вопрос